# React-Router: How to render different components on different parts of the page with one route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 2 links in my sidebar, this will change the link to "inbox" and "contacts" my problem is that when the route changes, the content of the sidebar doesn't change and I need to reload the page to render the content of it.

the links on the sidebar will append an ID and it can render perfectly the for example, the contact that has that ID in the route.

[image]

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
                <SidebarContainer/>

                <Route exact path="/inbox/:id" component={MessageContainer}/>
                <Route  path="/contacts" component={ContactContainer}/>
                <Route  path="/test" component={Test}/>

            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
}
```

Here's what I tried in the  Component

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
                <li className="padded-left">
                    <div>
                        <Link onClick={this._showInbox} to="/inbox" className="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">
                            <i className="material-icons">chat</i>
                        </Link>

                        <Link onClick={this._showContacts} to="/contacts" className="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">
                            <i className="material-icons">contacts</i>
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <Link to="/test" className="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat">
                        <i className="material-icons">Test</i>
                    </Link>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div className="divider">_</div>
                </li>

                <Route path="/inbox" component={ConversationContainer}/>
                <Route path="/contacts" component={ContactsContainer}/>
            </ul>



        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand. But you want to re-render the sidebar each time you are in `MessageContainer` `ContactContainer` and `Test` components?

Comment: I want to render a different component to sidebar and my main content when for example, when I'm in "inbox" route. But the component that I wanna render in the sidebar does'nt get rendered.

Comment: Oh, so the SideBar Container should change in different routes right?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't get rendered automatically, But whenever i refresh the page, It gets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I won't render the `SideBarContainer` inside the Router. You have to take into account that, when you navigate, the only thing that will be triggered to be rendered is the component inside the Route. Your Sidebar will always stay the same unless you refresh the page (here, the whole `App` is triggered to be rendered again)

As you are expecting the `SideBar` to change given a specific Route, you should render it inside the components of `<Route />` .